# In Perl, how does readline assign to $_ in a loop condition but not elsewhere?

Tags: perl

How is readline implemented in Perl?

Question is why readline sets $_ if readline is used in a loop condition such as:

```
while(<>) {
  #here $_ is set
  print;
}
```

On the contrary, if we just do

```
<>;
print;  #$_ is not set here
```

It will not print anything?

How is this implemented? How does the function know it is used in a loop condition statement? Or it is just a built-in behavior so designed that way?

Comment: This behavior is described in [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators): "Ordinarily you must assign the returned value to a variable, but there is one situation where an automatic assignment happens. If and only if the input symbol is the only thing inside the conditional of a `while` statement (even if disguised as a `for(;;)` loop), the value is automatically assigned to the global variable `$_`, destroying whatever was there previously. (This may seem like an odd thing to you, but you'll use the construct in almost every Perl script you write.)"

Comment: Downvoters care to comment on why? (One of many posts that got downvoted but no comment on that)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, there's nothing special about the implementation of `readline`.  It never sets `$_`.  Instead, there's a special case in the Perl compiler that examines the condition of a `while` loop and rewrites certain conditions internally.

For example, `while (<>) {}` gets rewritten into

```
while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    ();
}
```

You can see this with `perl -MO=Deparse -e 'while (<>) {}'`.

This is documented under [I/O Operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators):

> Ordinarily you must assign the returned value to a variable, but there is one situation where an automatic assignment happens. If and only if the input symbol is the only thing inside the conditional of a `while` statement (even if disguised as a `for(;;)` loop), the value is automatically assigned to the global variable `$_`, destroying whatever was there previously.

It's also mentioned in [Loop Control & For Loops in perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Loop-Control).

Answer (score 2):

`while` is a special case here assigning to `$_`. In the second case you just read everything on the command line and throw it away immediately. For further details, read the docs: https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#I-O-Operators

Comment: The second case doesn't read *everything* on the command line and throw it away, only the first argument: `echo foo > foo; echo bar > bar; perl -we '<>; print <>' foo bar` prints `bar`

Answer (score 0):

Perl functions can behave differently in different [*contexts*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context).

Your first example is a scalar context. Your second example is a void context.

You can determine the calling context of a function by using the built-in [`wantarray`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html).

[`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) declares all the places where `$_` is modified or used:

> Here are the places where Perl will assume `$_` even if you don't use it:
>
> The following functions use `$_` as a default argument:
>
> abs, alarm, chomp, chop, chr, chroot, cos, defined, eval, evalbytes, exp, fc, glob, hex, int, lc, lcfirst, length, log, lstat, mkdir, oct, ord, pos, print, printf, quotemeta, readlink, readpipe, ref, require, reverse (in scalar context only), rmdir, say, sin, split (for its second argument), sqrt, stat, study, uc, ucfirst, unlink, unpack.
>
> All file tests (`-f` , `-d`) except for `-t`, which defaults to STDIN. See -X
>
> The pattern matching operations `m//`, `s///` and `tr///` (aka `y///`) when used without an `=~` operator.
>
> The default iterator variable in a `foreach` loop if no other variable is supplied.
>
> The implicit iterator variable in the `grep()` and `map()` functions.
>
> The implicit variable of `given()`.
>
> The default place to put the next value or input record when a `<FH>`, `readline`, `readdir` or `each` operation's result is tested by itself as the sole criterion of a `while` test. Outside a `while` test, this will not happen.

Comment: This is true but irrelevant. `while (<>)` is a special case in the compiler.